# Merging different length data sets in R by matching values in columns?

Tags: r, merge

I have two data sets. One looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Book=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 Character=c('Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda'),
                 Target=c('Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally'),
                 Word=c('time', 'good', 'like', 'time', 'good', 'like', 'time', 'good', 'like'),
                 Total=c(1,2,4,2,4,3,2,4,4))
```

And the other looks something like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Character=c('Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda'),
                 Word=c('time', 'good', 'like'),
                 AllTotal=c(5,10,11))
```

What I am trying to do is merge the sets, keeping the same dimensions as df + 1 new column (AllTotal). For example, I want to show that Sally said the word 'time' to Jessie 1 time in Book 1 out of a total of 5 times throughout the dataset.  The final table layout would like something like this:

```
df3 <- data.frame(Book=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
                 Character=c('Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda'),
                 Target=c('Jessie', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Jessie', 'Sally', 'Sally', 'Jessie', 'Linda', 'Sally'),
                 Word=c('time', 'good', 'like', 'time', 'good', 'like', 'time', 'good', 'like'),
                 Total=c(1,2,4,2,4,3,2,4,4),
                 AllTotal=c(5,10,11,5,10,11,5,10,11))
```

I need some kind of merge or matching code, such that whenever  'word' from df2 matches 'word' from df, a new column is created in df (AllTotal) that places the corresponding AllTotal value from df2.

My actual datasets do not run in a consistent pattern the way my examples do, so I can't just repeat the AllTotal values the way I did in my examples.

I'm new to R and coding and so I don't know all of the proper terms. I hope what I'm asking makes sense from the examples I provided. I have tried various versions of merge, inner_join, and for loops, and can't seem to get the right answer. Since I don't know what the proper term is for what I'm trying to do, my searches have been unhelpful.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you want is just an inner join, since `merge(df,df2,by=c("Character","Word"))` seems to match your `df3` result. Is there something going wrong which means this doesn't work?

Comment: I think this worked, although it rearranges my column order (not a big deal). I didn't know to use c() in by= and was trying to match using a crazy for loop when the merge didn't do what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Answer (score 1):

As @thelatemail notes in their comment, an inner join by `Character` and `Word` seems to address your primary question:

> `result <- merge(df,df2,by=c("Character","Word"))`

You can re-order the column based on the value in the `Book` column using:

> `result <- result[order(result$Book),c(3,1,4,2,5,6)]`